# Обработка нажатий на Actor в libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

Как лучше узнать, было ли нажатие на какого-то
актёра в libgdx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [`InputListener`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputListener.html):

```
actor.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                Gdx.app.log("Example", "touch started at (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
                return false;
        }

        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                Gdx.app.log("Example", "touch done at (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
        }
 });
```

Возможно ещё понадобится вызов [`actor.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled)`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#setTouchable-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Touchable-).